# Linkedin - Unable to retrieve access token

Tags: php, wordpress, linkedin-api

I am getting below error while calling Linkedin API for access token:

"Unable to retrieve access token: appid/redirect uri/code verifier does not match authorization code. Or authorization code expired. Or external member binding exists"

here is the link what I am calling:

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?client_id=L1kfji328dfpoef&client_secret=klOpdfkJHGHuLOm14sdfkOj&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://example.com/linkedin-redirect&code=AQUIdkfdiksdr4D18sdfkiHk52LX5pX_T4AgKOKHU45Hrt7Bcu0ln8d2PITq8DuvNkVftV-plJ2tvOU4TnMAQ-nksdldTYkL902G9p0MKLKkljsd9mtNjjzBgq-lFqlcqtD4T2mYWmW498fJ7GbkDpyiQXHFo6xFsbSdrJxe3dJgh2A5edgpprm3vAY9REVM-Osdfki1

Can someone please suggest what I am doing wrong or something missed here. I already goes through most of the answers provided here but no luck.

Comment: As a best practice, never share your Client ID or Secret.

Comment: Thanks! but its all dummy key's

Answer (score 0):

You should be authenticated and ask for a token. 
Then when you have the token you can proceed to your request.

It's because LinkedIn is using [Oauth2 auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that your Client ID, Client Secret, and Redirect URI match the configuration of your LinkedIn Developer Application authorization settings.

Comment: Yeah its all matching.

Comment: Try submitting a ticket to linkedin.zendesk.com and include all of your Application and request information.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I tried using these API with android and specifically with AppAuth library. This library automatically includes also code_verifier parameter in the request, and if you add it you will get a different response. Code verifier can be a randomized string, but you must send the same to both `/oauth/v2/authorization` and `/oauth/v2/accessToken`.

After adding that I'm getting a different error, which is just `access_denied` with a `500 Internal Server Error`. From here, I don't have any idea on what is happening, and LinkedIn developer support is just a joke.

PS: code_verifier parameter is not mentioned in LinkedIn's doc, but the server asks for it and it is a STANDARD parameter for OAuth2 as you can see [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636)

PPS: Are you using a POST request with `Content-Type` = `x-www-form-urlencoded`? The URL you posted here seems like a GET with parameters passed as query params instead of a POST with form urlencoded params

EDIT: I finally got it working! You don't need `code_verifier`, what did the trick for me was to REMOVE the `state` parameter. Once I removed it I got the access token. I hate linkedin more than ever.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you to get the access token

```
       $params = array('grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => $this->api_key,
            'client_secret' => $this->api_secret,
            'code' => $_GET['code'],
            'redirect_uri' => base_url().$this->redirect,
        );
        // Access Token request
        $url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?' . http_build_query($params);
        $data_len = strlen(http_build_query($params));
        // Tell streams to make a POST request
        $context = stream_context_create(
                array('http' =>
                    array('method' => 'POST','header'=> 'Content-Length: 0'
                    )
                )
        );

        // Retrieve access token information
        $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        $token = json_decode($response);
        return $token->access_token;
```

Comment: I received _failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request_
 error